# Which is better implementation? <id, <xid, object>> or <id, object>

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I am trying to store 3 values. The last value is an object which can be accessed by XID. The main ID can be used to get the object.

I can think of two ways to implement this. Which would be a better approach? Also, which is better in terms of thread-safe and faster lookups?

1. Create a class and add it to the HashMap.

   ```
   public class TestMap {

        private int xid;
        private XObject xobject;

        public TestMap(int xid, XObject xobject) {

            this.xid = xid;
            this.object = object;
        }

        public int getXid() { return xid; }
        public XObject getXOBject { return xobject; }

   }

   map.put(ID, new TestMap(xid, xobject));
   ```
2. Create a nested HashMap

   ```
     HashMap<id, HashMap<xid, XObject>> map = new HashMap<>();

     map.put(id, new HashMap() {{ put(xid, xobject); }} );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you access it by the main ID, do you first need to specify the XID?

I'm assuming that you do not.  In this case, I would make two Maps.

One is a `Map<id,object>` which you use when looking up by `id`.  The second is a `Map<xid,object>` which you use when looking up by `xid`.